# Redirect to brand page after click on the brand logo

Tags: permalinks

I've designed a product page. I've added a brand from the attribute with a logo.
[image]

However, when I click on the logo it is redirecting me to this link:

```
....com/?taxonomy=pa_brands&term=midea
```

My expectation is to redirect to the following link:

```
......com/brand/midea
```

How can I achieve this without any plugin? Thank you.

Comment: can you edit the question to include the code that implements this? It's not clear how you created this so it's difficult to know the exact steps to answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call the function

```php
the_custom_logo();
```

and then on appearence choose your logo.
if this option is not available in appearance, you need to add the theme support to functions.php

```php
add_theme_support('custom-logo');
```

this redirectes to home page, if you need to redirect to a custom url
you can use

```php
<a href="<?= home_url() ?>/brand/midea"><img src="yourimage_path"></a>
```